# Loading email templates in a Craft 3 plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, emails

I've been struggling to make this work within a plugin. I have a html file in my templates folder called _email.html. I try to load it in my plugin but then I get an error. This is my code:

```
Craft::$app->mailer->compose('_email.html', ['body' => $emailBody])
            ->setFrom($fromMail)
            ->setTo($toMail)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->send();
```

The problem is that the Yii mailer is looking in the vendor folder instead of the templates folder.

This is the error I get:

`The view file does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/mail/_email`

Even when I try going back to the templates folder it doesn't seem to work and I get the following error:

`The view file does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/mail/../../../../../../templates/_email`

I found out that if I copy and paste the contents of the _email.html file and do the following it does work, but this obviously is a pretty bad workaround

```
->setHtmlBody("<!DOCTYPE html......")
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure since when this is possible, but there is a way nicer way of doing this now:

```php
<?php
$mailer = Craft::$app->getMailer();
$mailer->htmlLayout = false;
$mailer->textLayout = false;
$mailer->setViewPath('@templates/mailer');
$mailer->compose('_template_name.twig', ['user' => $user])
    ->setTo('example@example.com')
    ->setSubject('This is the subject')
    ->setTextBody('Text fallback')
    ->send();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to set the template mode to 'SITE', to let Craft know where to look for the template:

```
$view = \Craft::$app->getView();         
if ($view->getTemplateMode() !== $view::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE) {
    $view->setTemplateMode($view::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
}

Craft::$app->mailer->compose('_email.html', ['body' => $emailBody])
    ->setFrom($fromMail)
    ->setTo($toMail)
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->send();
```